# dynamically created li click event not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have unordered list defined in html file

```
<ul id="listbox-groups"></ul>
```

and i dynamically create li elements

```
function AddGroups(){
   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
       var id = groups[i].split("-")[0];
       var name = groups[i].split("-")[1];
       $('#listbox-groups').append('<li id="' + id + '" class="listbox-li"><a href="#" class="listbox-li-a" style="text-decoration: none">' + name + '</a></li>');
   }
};
```

Now i am trying to catch click event on created li element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#listbox-groups li").on("click", function(event) {
        //some code
    });
</script>
```

I also tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", "#listbox-groups li", function(event) {
        //some code
    });
</script>
```

and few other things i found here but nothing worked for me.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your code inside ready function and it will work with your second attempt that using event delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**, check snippet bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$(function(){
    var groups = ['test-1','test-2','test-3'];
    var len = groups.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      var id = groups[i].split("-")[0];
      var name = groups[i].split("-")[1];
      $('#listbox-groups').append('<li id="' + id + '" class="listbox-li"><a href="#" class="listbox-li-a" style="text-decoration: none">' + name + '</a></li>');
    }

    $(document).on("click", "#listbox-groups li", function(event) {
      alert($(this).text()+" clicked");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listbox-groups"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the fiddle. seems you need to avoid default action of aHref. https://jsfiddle.net/vh08vw84/

```
function AddGroups(){
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       var id = i;
       var name = i;
       $('#listbox-groups').append('<li id="' + id + '" class="listbox-li"><a href="#" class="listbox-li-a" style="text-decoration: none">' + name + '</a></li>');
   }
};
AddGroups();

$("#listbox-groups li").on("click", function(event) {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
        return false;
    });
```